# Need to copy files with .3GP extension

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I'm not sure why this question has been closed and got -points, but if nobody can answer it then can someone point me in the direction to where I can get an answer for this? thanks. Here it is again:

The file doesn't copy over with `Get-ChildItem` or `Copy-Item`. Here is the output of the actual powershell window without running the script:

```
PS C:\> Open-Device 10.42.233.237
Connecting to device '10.42.233.237' ...


Device Name : 10.42.233.237
Device IP   : 10.42.233.237
Device Host :

Run 'Get-Variable Device*' to see variables set for the connected session.


DEVICE C:\
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path "V:\WP\QM\Audio\Decode\Automated" -Filter *.3g2 | Copy-Item -Destination C:\test\MinTE
DEVICE C:\
PS C:\> putd -Path "V:\WP\QM\Audio\Decode\Automated" -Filter "*.3g2" -Destination "C:\test\MinTE"
Put-Device : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Path'.
At line:1 char:6
+ putd -Path "V:\WP\QM\Audio\Decode\Automated" -Filter "*.3g2" -Destination "C:\te ...
+      ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Put-Device], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Texus.Shells.PowerShell.PutFileDeviceCmdlet

DEVICE C:\
PS C:\>
```

putd is short for Put-Device. the Get-ChildItem and Copy-Item does not work while connected to a device. They are unrecognized as cmdlet functions. Here is the full script to get an idea:

```
param(
$SourcePath, $DestinationPath
)

# Display something just as a sanity check
Write-Output "Starting Setup";

# Waits to gather input
Start-Sleep -m 1000

# Connect to device
Open-Device $env:IP_Address | out-null

# Waits to establish a connection to the device
Start-Sleep -m 2000

# Copy a files to the device
Write-Output "Copying testcases and support files..."
putd $env:source\*.mp4 C:\test\MinTE | out-null
putd $env:source\*.mp3 C:\test\MinTE | out-null
putd $env:source\*.wma C:\test\MinTE | out-null
putd $env:source\*.m4a C:\test\MinTE | out-null
putd $env:source\*.amr C:\test\MinTE | out-null
putd $env:source\*.wav C:\test\MinTE | out-null
putd $env:source\*.3g2 C:\test\MinTE | out-null
putd $env:source\*.3gp C:\test\MinTE | out-null
putd $env:source\*.xml C:\test\MinTE | out-null


# Closes Connection to device
Close-Device

# Allows space for easy reading for the user
Write-Output " "
Write-Output " "
Write-Output " "
Write-Output " "

# Tells the user the script ran successfully
Write-Output "... Setup Successful (NO REBOOT REQUIRED)"

exit;
```

This script is called using a batch file with two variables input by the user when the batch file command is executed. It was tested and works with all other file types except for ".3gp" and ".3g2". One thing I noticed when adding a "3" anywhere in the .ps1 script (using notpad++) the color changes to orange, and adding a "gp" anywhere in the .ps1 script (using notpad++) changes the color to light blue. This tells me these two might be switches, but I'm not sure what.

Also, here is the batch file used to execute this script if needed to reproduce the error:

```
@echo off
::Conditions leading to errors if the batch script is not executed correctly
if "%1"=="" goto error1
if "%2"=="" goto error2

::Allows user to set the "Source Path" to copy the testcase files from
set source=%1
::Allows user to set the "Destination Path" to copy the testcase files from
set IP_Address=%2

:: Does a health check to ensure source path is valid
IF NOT EXIST "%source%" goto error3
:: Does a health check to ensure Device IP Address is valid
ping -n 1 -w 100 %IP_Address% 1>nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto error4

::Tells the user what the "Source" and "Destination" Paths are
echo Source Path = %1
echo Destination Path = %2
echo.
powershell.exe -File "BVT_AudioDecode_Automated.ps1" %1 %2 -NoProfile -NoExit


goto end
:error1
echo.
echo Error Syntax: BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat "Source_Path\AudioDecode_Testcase_Folder" "Device IP Address"
echo.
echo For example: BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat V:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237
echo              -or-
echo              BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat C:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237
echo.
echo.
goto end
:error2
echo.
echo Error Syntax: BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat "Source_Path\AudioDecode_Testcase_Folder"     "Device IP Address"
echo.
echo For example: BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat V:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237
echo              -or-
echo              BVT_AudioDecode_Setup.bat C:\WP\BVT\Audio\Decode 10.42.233.237
echo.
echo.
goto end
:error3
echo.
echo Error: Invalid Path
echo %source%
goto end
:error4
echo.
echo Error: Invalid IP Address
echo %IP_Address%
goto end
:end
```

I did notice that `Open-Device` and `Putd` (short for Put-Device) has a different module name than the other commands when I ran the `get-command`. If nobody recognizes this list, then maybe I came to the wrong place:

```
Cmdlet          Add-FederatedDeviceHost                            TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Add-FederatedEnvironment                           TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Add-VirtualMachine                                 TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          CD-Device                                          TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Close-Device                                       TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Cmd-Device                                         TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Copy-Device                                        TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Create-FederatedVirtualDeviceHost                  TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Create-Federation                                  TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Debug-Device                                       TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Del-Device                                         TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Deploy-Device                                      TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Dir-Device                                         TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Exec-Device                                        TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Filter-Result                                      TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Get-ChildPrimitive                                 TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Get-Device                                         TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Get-ResultSummary                                  TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Get-SuiteName                                      TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Get-TaskOutputPath                                 TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Get-VirtualMachineNames                            TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Kill-Device                                        TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Merge-Reports                                      TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          MkDir-Device                                       TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Mount-VirtualDisk                                  TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Move-Device                                        TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Open-Device                                        TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Put-Device                                         TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Reg-Device                                         TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Remove-FederatedDeviceHost                         TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Remove-VirtualMachine                              TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          RmDir-Device                                       TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Set-VirtualMachine                                 TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Show-Result                                        TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Start-VirtualMachine                               TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Stop-VirtualMachine                                TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Test-Device                                        TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          TList-Device                                       TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Type-Device                                        TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Unmount-VirtualDisk                                TexusCmdlets
Cmdlet          Validate-FederatedDeviceHost                       TexusCmdlets
```

Comment: What is "Texus"? I can't find any reference to it via Google that isn't a company or this post. Is it a custom PSSnapin or module, and if so why is it in a Microsoft namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer!

```
PS U:\> get-help put-device -full

Do you want to run Update-Help?
The Update-Help cmdlet downloads the newest Help files for Windows PowerShell modules and installs them on your
computer. For more details, see the help topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink ?LinkId=210614.
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): y

NAME
    Put-Device

SYNOPSIS
    Copies one or more files from the host machine to the connected device.

SYNTAX
    Put-Device [-Source] [<string>] [[-Destination] [<string>]] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    The Put-Device cmdlet copies one or more files from the host machine to the connected device.
    Absolute paths are used as-is and relative paths are treated relative to the
    current working directory, either on the device or the host.


PARAMETERS
    -Source [<string>]
        The path of the source file(s) on the host ('*' and '?' wildcards are supported).

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    0
        Default value
        Accept pipeline input?
        Accept wildcard characters?

    -Destination [<string>]
        The path of the destination file or directory on the device.
        If omitted, the current working directory on the device will be used.

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    1
        Default value
        Accept pipeline input?
        Accept wildcard characters?

    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer and OutVariable. For more information, see
        about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).

INPUTS

OUTPUTS


RELATED LINKS
```

After obtaining this information, this is the correct command given to solve the problem:

```
putd -Source "$env:source\*.3gp" -Destination "C:\test\MinTE" | out-null
```

I'll leave this up in case anyone can learn from this.

Comment: Thanks for the asked and answered, this SDK intended for windows mobile and included in the new windows core is dangerously under-documented. Well done!